# Excluding small chunks of pixels from Image .Net

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, aforge

I have black image with white lines. Is it possible to exclude chunks of whihte pixels, that are smaller than specific number? For example: change color of chunks of pixels that are made from less than 10 pixels from white to black.
Original Image:
[image]

Image on the output(small areas of white pixels are removed):
[image]

Right now I work with *AForge* library for *C#,* but *C++* ways of solving this are also apreciated(Open CV, for example). And hint, on how this functionality might be called are also appreciated.

Comment: Google for "area opening". I don't know if OpenCV includes this filter, but it does exactly what you need.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks a lot. It actually helped me in research. And I've found ready solution for this from AForge, called BlobsFiltering, which solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

Without worrying to much about your details, it does seem trivially simple

1. Use bitmap in 32bits and use LockBits to get scanlines and direct pointer access to the array.
2. Scan every pixel with 2 for loops

   - Every time you find one that matches your target color, scan left right and up and down (X) Amount of pixels to determine if it matches your requirements,
   - If it does, leave the pixel, if not change it.
   - if you wanted more speed you could chuck this all in a parallel workload, also there is probably more you could do with a mask array to save you researching dead paths (just a thought)

***Note***, Obviously you can smarten this up a bit

**Exmaple**

```
// lock the array for direct access
var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(Bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Bitmap.PixelFormat);
// get the pointer
var  scan0Ptr = (int*)_bitmapData.Scan0;
// get the stride
var  stride = _bitmapData.Stride / BytesPerPixel;

// local method
void Workload(Rectangle bounds)
{
   // this is if synchronous, Bounds is just the full image rectangle
   var rect = bounds ?? Bounds; 
   var white = Color.White.ToArgb();
   var black = Color.Black.ToArgb();

   // scan all x
   for (var x = rect.Left; x < rect.Right; x++)
   {
      var pX = scan0Ptr + x;

      // scan all y
      for (var y = rect.Top; y < rect.Bottom; y++)
      {            
         if (*(pX + y * stride ) != white)
         {
            // this will turn it to monochrome
            // so add your threshold here, ie some more for loops
            //*(pX + y * Stride) = black;
         }
      }
   }
}

// unlock the bitmap
bitmap.UnlockBits(_bitmapData);
```

**To parallel'ize it**

You could use something like this to break your image up into smaller regions

```
public static List<Rectangle> GetSubRects(this Rectangle source, int size)
{
   var rects = new List<Rectangle>();

   for (var x = 0; x < size; x++)
   {
      var width = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(source.Width / (double)size));
      var xCal = 0;

      if (x == size - 1)
      {
         xCal = source.Width - (width * size);
      }
      for (var y = 0; y < size; y++)
      {

         var height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(source.Height / (double)size));
         var yCal = 0;

         if (y == size - 1)
         {
            yCal = source.Height - (height * size) ;
         }

         rects.Add(new Rectangle(width * x, height * y, width+ xCal, height + yCal));
      }
   }

   return rects;
}
```

And this

```
private static void DoWorkload(Rectangle bounds, ParallelOptions options, Action<Rectangle?> workload)
{
   if (options == null)
   {
      workload(null);
   }
   else
   {
      var size = 5 // how many rects to work on, ie 5 x 5
      Parallel.ForEach(bounds.GetSubRects(size), options, rect => workload(rect));
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
DoWorkload(Bounds, options, Workload);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It wasn't necessary to post code snippets as well. But I really appreciate it. I will practice with this tomorrow. I actually thought, that there is some solution for this already. Thanks a lot anyway